# Convergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin\big(\frac1{x^2}\big)}{\frac\pi2 -\ \rm{arccotg}\ x}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

> **Problem:** does the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\sin\big(\frac1{x^2}\big)}{\frac\pi2 -\ \rm{arccotg}\ x}$ converge?

I know that the function is continuous on $(0,1]$, that the problem is at $x = 0$ and that I'll have to use Abel's (or Dirichlet's) convergence criteria. But I cannot find the functions $g, h$ so that $f = gh$, $g$ is monotonic and $f$ is "known" (in the sense that antiderivative is known or $\int_0^1 f$ converges.)

Could anyone provide a hint?

**Edit:** One of my previous attempts was to write

$$
f(x) = (-2)\frac{\sin{\frac1{x^2}}}{x^3}\frac{x^3}{-2\big(\frac\pi2 - {\rm arccotg}\ x\big)}
$$

Then I can prove that the first factor converges (using $t = \frac1{x^2}$). The problem is that I do not know how the prove the monotonicity of the second factor.

Comment: HINT: Split your integral in both and treat the integrand on a neighborhood of $0$ by Taylor expansion.

Comment: Thanks! But how will that work for me? The function changes signs at $(0, 1)$, therefore, I cannot use the limit test. And the expansion can only be done for ${\rm arccotg} x$.

Comment: I think there is a typo: shouldn't it be "or $\int_0^1 f$ converges"?

Comment: Oh, sure. I'm sorry, I'll fix that.

Comment: An observation, that may make things a little bit easier: $\frac \pi 2 - \text{arc cotg} x = \text{arc tg} x$ for $x>0$.

Comment: @eudes, I'll try to use that.

Comment: @eudes, that may be it! That will simplify the calculation of the derivative. Great!

Comment: I was just meaning to tell you to calculate the derivative :)
A quick Czech-up ;) of [the derivative at WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff%28x^3%2Farctanx%29) shows that it's positive above $0$. To get it by hand, remember that $\text{arc tg} x > x/2$ close to $0$, because $\text{tg} x < 2 x$ close to $0$.
Good luck!

Comment: @eudes, thanks! That was the piece I missed. If you formulate that into an answer, I'll be glad to Czech the accept-mark ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that $\frac \pi2 - \operatorname{arc ctg} x = \operatorname{arc tg} x$ for $x\geq 0$. If anything, this makes the problem shorter to write, and maybe easier to think of. Also, bear in mind that $\operatorname{arc tg} x\approx x$ near $0$, more precisely:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0 } \frac{\operatorname{arc tg} x}x = 1
\quad \text{and} \quad
\frac 12 x \stackrel{(\star)}< \operatorname{arc tg} x < x \quad \text{for } x\in(0, \varepsilon)
$$
(in fact at least for $x\in(0, 2\pi/3)$ and actually for $x\in (0,0.7421\dots\pi)$; if you don't know these, see the remark at the end).

Now, if we write the integrand as you suggest (and using my little note, and simplifying a bit):
$$
\frac{\sin{\frac1{x^2}}}{x^3}\frac{x^3}{\operatorname{arc tg} x}
$$
and you're asking about the monotonicity of the second factor, then we should try the derivative. I'll leave the calculation as an exercise – let's examine the result:
$$
\big(\frac{x^3}{\operatorname{arc tg} x}\big)' = \frac{x^2}{(\operatorname{arc tg}x)^2} \bigg(3 \operatorname{arc tg} x - \frac x{x^2+1}\bigg).
$$
Because of the inequalities: $(\star)$ and $x^2 + 1 > 1$:
$$
3 \operatorname{arc tg} x - \frac x{x^2+1} > \frac 32 x -  x = \frac 12 x > 0
$$
for $x\in(0,\varepsilon)$, so the second factor is increasing in $(0,\varepsilon)$ (in fact, in $(0, \infty)$), which should yield the convergence of the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^\varepsilon (\dots)$.

*Remark*. The limit follows from the limit $\frac{\operatorname{tg} x}x\to 1$ and further from $\frac{\sin x}x\to 1$, which is classic, I think. The inequality $\operatorname{arc tg}x < x$ follows from $\operatorname{tg}x > x$, which I suppose is also classic. Finally, given the limit, it must be $\operatorname{arc tg}x > \frac 12 x$ close to zero: for some $x\in(0,\varepsilon)$. The coefficient $\frac 12$ isn't special: anything in $(\frac 13, 1)$ will do fine here, but $\frac 12$ came first to my mind.

Comment: @David Can't believe it took me well over hour to write this. You in turn are very quick. Thanks for accepting. I fact, what I actually did were only two little steps, I just expanded it in the answer, so that it is complete and helpful for the "general public". You already did most of the work. Happy to help anyway!

Comment: never mind about that, what I regard the best is that I had somenone to bear the burden with me for a while :). You have a nice time!

Comment: @David Well, this pleasure might continue. I see a problem, don't know yet how serious it is.
I couldn't understand what you wrote: that you can prove convergence for the 1st factor. In fact, WolframAlpha would claim [it doesn't converge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(sin(1%2Fx^2)%2Fx^3%2C+x%3D0..1)). So, are you sure about that?

Comment: @David Ok, so it turns I don't remember the Abel-Dirichlet criterion :/  It seems fine. Although still I wouldn't say that the 1st factor "converges".

Comment: @David Sorry for disturbing and have a nice Sunday!

Comment: You're right. I was a little too fast about the 1st factor. In fact, I am not sure it converges at all. What I should've said is that $\sin(\frac1{x^2})/x^3$ can be written as $g(\omega(x))\omega'(x)$ for $g(y) := \sin y$, $\omega(x) = \frac1{x^2}$. Therefore, the primitive function at $(0, 1)$ is $-\cos(\frac1{x^2})$, which is bound. Not disturbing at all :).

Comment: @David Yes, and $\cos(1/x^2)$ doesn't have a limit for $x\to 0$, the integral doesn't converge, but it is uniformly bounded. It's all alright for me now!

Comment: It's good having that "peer reviewed" :). I'll update my post not to confuse anyone.